# MVC Bundle not working with Release Configuration (Debug is False), CSS and JS not loading

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I release MVC.Net application using release mode, the below setting will be available in the web.config file.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

When we do the above, the site loaded with CSS and JavaScript and developer tools show the bunch of URL bundles returning 404 errors.

I have also tried the below code which also not loading the script and style sheets.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Can someone help me fix this issue? Due to the above issues, my application is running into Caching issue with script and CSS file. Each of my new releases, I have to ask my customers to clear the browser cache to make sure that new functionalities are working fine.

Comment: are you saying you get 404 for the static assets ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes! Though EnableOptimizations is set to true!

Comment: Is this after deployment or in visual studio? If post deployment check that the files are included correctly in the solution to be deployed (right click on the file and properties)

Comment: Its happening after the deployment. Okay I am applying what you have told me to do. @TomJohn

Comment: Did that suggestion work?

Comment: Yes, It did! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the files are included correctly in the solution to be deployed (right click on the file and select properties).